# How to find the character entity in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have string "Saraswathi " and used deblank to remove the trailing whitespace, but was unsuccesful because it is not a whitespace at the end but must be something else. How can one find out what it is exactly in Matlab?

In the following code, *aa* is the original string from a cell in excel data sheet, and *aaa* is my replication of the same with a trailing white space. Clearly *aa ~= aaa* indicates that the trailing space in *aa* is something else. I would like to deblank any kind of traling chars in the string *aa*. How can I achieve that in Matlab?

```
K>> aa

aa = 

    "Saraswathi "

K>> aaa

aaa = 

    "Saraswathi "

K>> aa == aaa

ans =

  logical

   0
```

Upon further digging, it is clear that the trailing char in *aa* is ASCII 160 which is clearly defined as irremovable by deblank in the Matlab docs. Is there any other way to remove this ASCII 160 from a string?

```
K>> double(convertStringsToChars(aa))

ans =

    83    97   114    97   115   119    97   116   104   105   160

K>> double(convertStringsToChars(aaa))

ans =

    83    97   114    97   115   119    97   116   104   105    32
```

Comment: `isstrprop(str,'alpha')` let's you select only standard alphanumeric characters.

Comment: It's not ASCII 160; it's Unicode 160. Matlab chars are UCS-2 Unicode characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know this character is the last element of the string, perhaps this will help

```
aa = aa(1:end-1)

> ans =
> 
>     'Saraswathi'
```

Another workaround, a little more complicated is:

```
strtrim(strrep(aa,sprintf('%c',160),' '))
```

The [strrep](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html) function substitutes the ASCII 160 char by a blank space and the [strtrim](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtrim.html) will remove the blank spaces